# @EnableJpaRepositories does not obey to @Primary annotated beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-test-mvc

I've simple Spring setup using `@Inject`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`. There is currently no need to have specific `@Configurations` for test, integration or production environments.

I'm now using the Spring test mvc framework and I'm introducing an `@TestConfig` containing mocked beans for my (Spring Data) Repository classes which also have the @Primary annotation.
But the `@EnableJpaRepositories` seems not to obey to the `@Primary` for the repository beans in my `TestConfig`.

Is there an easy way to solve this or should I really split everything up using specific profiles not enabling Spring Data JPA repositories?

Comment: Can you post stacktrace and configuration? One thing to take into account is that `@Primary` only works for beans which are detected by component-scanning for beans declared in xml it has to be declared in the xml configuration. In Java Config it has to be declared next to the @Bean annotation.

Comment: I am not sure I get the use case here. `@Primary`'s purpose is to select one *implementation* as the primary one. As we deal with interfaces here, how can you actually get to two Spring beans in an `ApplicationContext` for an interface? However, if you use `@Primary` on a manually implemented stub, this bean instance should trump the proxy generated by `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: Hi Oliver, The use case is I'm using a single (simple) Configuration class which also has the EnableJpaRepositories annotation. While executing my MVC tests (using the mvc test framework) I can't seem to mock my repositories. I tried creating a TestConfig with mocks for the repositories, but this does not work.

Comment: So how do you register the mock beans then? I'd assume an additional configuration class imported using `@Import`, containing `@Primary` `@Bean` methods should definitely trump the automatically registered ones. Also you could simply try naming the bean methods after the repository bean names. This should override the scanned ones as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Spring Boot's @ SpringBootApplication annotation. I'm not able to mock my repositories with @ Import and @ Primary @ Bean on the TestApplication class. Has anyone found a solution?